# What's minimum api for json object in android

Tags: android, json

I want to create app and reed data from server , I need to know what's minimum api level ,for support JsonObject in android

Sry my English is bad .

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the documentation on Android Developers: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

JSONObject was added in API level 1 so that's the minimum API level.

Answer (score 0):

All Level of android API starting from API 1 upto the latest API supports **JSON**

Answer (score -1):

There are so many API for JsonObject, one of them is 'gson' api.

download it from here...https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Example:

Json String

```
{
  NAME:"user 345",
  P_LANGUAGE:"Java",
  LOCATION:"Malta"      
}
```

Pojo class

```
public class Person {

    private String NAME;
    private String LOCATION;
    private Exam EXAM;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return NAME + " - " + LOCATION ;
    }
}
```

Json Reader

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class JsonToJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try(Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(JsonToJava.class.getResourceAsStream("/Server2.json"), "UTF-8")){
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            Person p = gson.fromJson(reader, Person.class);
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide